# k8s PodSecurityPolicy. Drop all capabilities except one

Tags: kubernetes

I want to build a pod security policy where I drop all the capabilities and then enable only CHOWN.

The problem is that it seems that "requiredDropCapabilities: ALL" is the main rule and if I configure it to ALL then I can not add individual capabilities with AllowedCapabilities or DefaultAddCapabilities.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/

> RequiredDropCapabilities - The capabilities which must be dropped from
>   containers. These capabilities are removed from the default set, and
>   must not be added. Capabilities listed in RequiredDropCapabilities
>   must not be included in AllowedCapabilities or DefaultAddCapabilities

How could I deny all capabilities except one?

--EDIT

This is my example:

PodSecurityPolicy:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  name: a-pot-root
spec:
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  forbiddenSysctls:
  - '*'
  allowedCapabilities:
  - CHOWN
  requiredDropCapabilities:
  - ALL
  fsGroup:
    ranges:
    - max: 65535
      min: 1
    rule: MustRunAs
  runAsUser:
    rule: RunAsAny
  seLinux:
    rule: RunAsAny
  supplementalGroups:
    ranges:
    - max: 65535
      min: 1
    rule: MustRunAs
  volumes:
  - configMap
  - emptyDir
  - projected
  - secret
  - downwardAPI
  - persistentVolumeClaim
```

Then inside the container there is no CHOWN capability:

```
root@hellonode-6d654c57b8-b8hz8:/app# capsh --print
Current: =
Bounding set =
Securebits: 00/0x0/1'b0
 secure-noroot: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-suid-fixup: no (unlocked)
 secure-keep-caps: no (unlocked)
uid=0(root)
gid=0(root)
groups=1(daemon)
```

Thx.

Comment: Can you please provide an example and/or be more specific regarding "I can not add individual capabilities"; does `kubectl` complain it's invalid? does it have no effect? Also, what values are you using for `allowPrivilegeEscalation` and `privileged`, if any?

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas I have edited the question with the details.

Comment: Thank you @Jxadro and if you set `allowPrivilegeEscalation: true` then does it change anything or still the same result?

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is comment the "- ALL", add all the "capability options" that are allowed by default [as documented here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities), and comment the capabilities I didn't require.

Caveat: I thought I would need only CHOWN, but ended needing some more.

```
  requiredDropCapabilities:
    # - ALL               # Drop all the usual capabilities
    - SETPCAP               # Modify process capabilities.
    - MKNOD               # Create special files using mknod(2).
    - AUDIT_WRITE           # Write records to kernel auditing log.
    # - CHOWN               # Make arbitrary changes to file UIDs and GIDs (see chown(2)).
    - NET_RAW               # Use RAW and PACKET sockets.
    # - DAC_OVERRIDE        # Bypass file read, write, and execute permission checks.
    # - FOWNER            # Bypass permission checks on operations that normally require the file system UID of the process to match the UID of the file.
    - FSETID                # Don’t clear set-user-ID and set-group-ID permission bits when a file is modified.
    - KILL                # Bypass permission checks for sending signals.
    # - SETGID            # Make arbitrary manipulations of process GIDs and supplementary GID list.
    # - SETUID            # Make arbitrary manipulations of process UIDs.
    - NET_BIND_SERVICE    # Bind a socket to internet domain privileged ports (port numbers less than 1024).
    - SYS_CHROOT            # Use chroot(2), change root directory.
    - SETFCAP               # Set file capabilities
```

Hope it helps. I was looking for answers but found first your question :)